# Unable to fix styled border around GridPane in Java FX

Tags: java, javafx

I am creating a Boggle game in Java 8 (using Java FX to create the GUI,) and I can't seem to figure out how to set a fixed border around my GridPane (the 16 letter dice) so that it does not resize itself according to the window.

I have purposely sized the window accordingly (to accommodate a sizable list of words the user can create,) and the thin white border I added to my GridPane continues to resize itself, even though I have applied the CSS styling (-fx-border-color and -fx-border-width) to only the GridPane, NOT the main BorderPane container that holds all children of the game. The GridPane resides in the Center position within the BorderPane.

Any thoughts?

[image]

Comment: You need to post code!

Answer (score 1):

If your outer pane is also a `GridPane`, you can set the `valignment` of your row and `halignment` of your column to `CENTER` (Version A). Alternatively, wrap your inner `GridPane` into an `HBox` and a `VBox` and set their respective `alignment` property to `CENTER` (Version B). Both will result in the same behavior:

[image: outcome]

### Main.java

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

### sample.fxml Version A

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>

<GridPane gridLinesVisible="true" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity"
          prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.1">
    <columnConstraints>
        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0"/>
        <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0"/>
        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0"/>
    </columnConstraints>
    <rowConstraints>
        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" valignment="CENTER" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
    </rowConstraints>
    <GridPane gridLinesVisible="true" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity"
              minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="50.0"
              style="-fx-border-color: #ff00ff; -fx-border-width: 1;" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
      <columnConstraints>
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0"/>
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0"/>
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0"/>
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0"/>
      </columnConstraints>
      <rowConstraints>
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
      </rowConstraints>
    </GridPane>
</GridPane>
```

### sample.fxml Version B

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<GridPane gridLinesVisible="true" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <columnConstraints>
        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
    </columnConstraints>
    <rowConstraints>
        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    </rowConstraints>
    <HBox alignment="CENTER" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
        <VBox alignment="CENTER">
            <GridPane gridLinesVisible="true" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity"
                      minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="50.0"
                      style="-fx-border-color: #ff00ff; -fx-border-width: 1;">
              <columnConstraints>
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0"/>
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0"/>
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0"/>
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0"/>
              </columnConstraints>
              <rowConstraints>
                  <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
                  <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
                  <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
                  <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
              </rowConstraints>
            </GridPane>
        </VBox>
    </HBox>
</GridPane>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, my GridPane is set within a BorderPane (in the center area.) When I resize my window, I assume the center area of the BorderPane is being adjusted as well, but I still don't understand why the CSS I've added to my GridPane (the thin white border) is being affected by the window size..

Comment: You should post your FXML or UI code then. Otherwise we can't know whats happening.